# Remove space on removing qt widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have a grid layout on top of which there are 4 group boxes. When I try to hide one of the QGroupBoxes using `groupBox->hide()`, the group box is not visible anymore. But the space is retained in the layout (I am **not** using `QSizePolicy` to retain the space)

How do I make sure that space is automatically used by the remaining widgets?

[image]

In the picture, I have hidden 'Group 2'. I want Group 3 to automatically fill up the space. How do I do this?

Comment: You want Group 3 to move to the top position but before that there are 2 cases, the first is to update the size of the widget and the second is to leave a space in place. Which one do you want?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to update the size of the widget (without leaving any space)

Comment: Did you use setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);

Comment: At least in Qt 4.x I knew that problem, however in Qt 5 it seems to work as expected. Can you show us your object tree?

Comment: Have you any spacer in between or max-height properties ? Why do you use a grid-box instead of vertical-box ?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the layout to do what you want, its child widgets have to 'behave' correctly.
I.e. if one of your group boxes contains a vertical spacer, it might mess up your layout.

I found that setting a stylesheet to the toplevel widget helps with debugging layout issues:

```
pWidget->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red;");
```

This will paint a red border around (some) widgets and clarifies who uses which space.

You could try to add a vertical spacer below the third group box to "push" them all upwards. If one of the group boxes is then set to invisible, the others should get pushed up and the space between group box 1 and 3 should disappear.